# How do I remove letters from Key in python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

i want to output the first three letters of each key and in all caps.
 i have :

```
bulbs = { 'DAFFODIL': 0.35, 'TULIP': 0.33, 'CROCUS': 0.25, 'HYACINTH': 0.75, 'BLUEBELL': 0.50}
```

i have tried

```
for keys in m_order.keys():
    m_order[keys.split(2)]
```

how do I get this:

```
DAF
TUL 
CRO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for keys in m_order.keys():
    print(key[:3].upper())
```